# Rstudio server probem: installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, linux, devtools, libgit2

R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10) -- "Kick Things"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

I want to install devtools in the Rstudio server, but failed all the time. Here are the results running the install.packages.

```
> install.packages("devtools") 
Installing package into ‘/GPUFS/smu_ymyu_1/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘gert’, ‘usethis’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gert_1.9.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 121017 bytes (118 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 118 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/usethis_2.1.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 342349 bytes (334 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 334 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/devtools_2.4.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 374718 bytes (365 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 365 KB

* installing *source* package ‘gert’ ...
** package ‘gert’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Using static libgit2 for Linux x86_64
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-DSTATIC_LIBGIT2 -I/tmp/RtmpK20lPh/R.INSTALL10915eb5334/gert/libgit2/include
Using PKG_LIBS=-L/tmp/RtmpK20lPh/R.INSTALL10915eb5334/gert/libgit2/lib -lgit2 -lrt -lpthread -lssh2 -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lpcre -lz
Configuration OK!
** libs
rm -f gert.so branch.o clone.o commit.o config.o conflicts.o files.o init.o merge.o rebase.o stash.o submodules.o tag.o utils.o version.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/app/centos/R/4.1.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -DSTATIC_LIBGIT2 -I/tmp/RtmpK20lPh/R.INSTALL10915eb5334/gert/libgit2/include -DR_NO_REMAP -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS  -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c branch.c -o branch.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/app/centos/R/4.1.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -DSTATIC_LIBGIT2 -I/tmp/RtmpK20lPh/R.INSTALL10915eb5334/gert/libgit2/include -DR_NO_REMAP -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS  -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c clone.c -o clone.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/app/centos/R/4.1.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -DSTATIC_LIBGIT2 -I/tmp/RtmpK20lPh/R.INSTALL10915eb5334/gert/libgit2/include -DR_NO_REMAP -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS  -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c commit.c -o commit.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/app/centos/R/4.1.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -DSTATIC_LIBGIT2 -I/tmp/RtmpK20lPh/R.INSTALL10915eb5334/gert/libgit2/include -DR_NO_REMAP -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS  -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c config.c -o config.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/app/centos/R/4.1.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -DSTATIC_LIBGIT2 -I/tmp/RtmpK20lPh/R.INSTALL10915eb5334/gert/libgit2/include -DR_NO_REMAP -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS  -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c conflicts.c -o conflicts.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/app/centos/R/4.1.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -DSTATIC_LIBGIT2 -I/tmp/RtmpK20lPh/R.INSTALL10915eb5334/gert/libgit2/include -DR_NO_REMAP -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS  -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c files.c -o files.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/app/centos/R/4.1.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -DSTATIC_LIBGIT2 -I/tmp/RtmpK20lPh/R.INSTALL10915eb5334/gert/libgit2/include -DR_NO_REMAP -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS  -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/app/centos/R/4.1.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -DSTATIC_LIBGIT2 -I/tmp/RtmpK20lPh/R.INSTALL10915eb5334/gert/libgit2/include -DR_NO_REMAP -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS  -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c merge.c -o merge.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/app/centos/R/4.1.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -DSTATIC_LIBGIT2 -I/tmp/RtmpK20lPh/R.INSTALL10915eb5334/gert/libgit2/include -DR_NO_REMAP -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS  -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c rebase.c -o rebase.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/app/centos/R/4.1.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -DSTATIC_LIBGIT2 -I/tmp/RtmpK20lPh/R.INSTALL10915eb5334/gert/libgit2/include -DR_NO_REMAP -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS  -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c stash.c -o stash.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/app/centos/R/4.1.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -DSTATIC_LIBGIT2 -I/tmp/RtmpK20lPh/R.INSTALL10915eb5334/gert/libgit2/include -DR_NO_REMAP -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS  -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c submodules.c -o submodules.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/app/centos/R/4.1.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -DSTATIC_LIBGIT2 -I/tmp/RtmpK20lPh/R.INSTALL10915eb5334/gert/libgit2/include -DR_NO_REMAP -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS  -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c tag.c -o tag.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/app/centos/R/4.1.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -DSTATIC_LIBGIT2 -I/tmp/RtmpK20lPh/R.INSTALL10915eb5334/gert/libgit2/include -DR_NO_REMAP -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS  -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c utils.c -o utils.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/app/centos/R/4.1.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -DSTATIC_LIBGIT2 -I/tmp/RtmpK20lPh/R.INSTALL10915eb5334/gert/libgit2/include -DR_NO_REMAP -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS  -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c version.c -o version.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/app/centos/R/4.1.1/lib64/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -o gert.so branch.o clone.o commit.o config.o conflicts.o files.o init.o merge.o rebase.o stash.o submodules.o tag.o utils.o version.o -L/tmp/RtmpK20lPh/R.INSTALL10915eb5334/gert/libgit2/lib -lgit2 -lrt -lpthread -lssh2 -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lpcre -lz -L/app/centos/R/4.1.1/lib64/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/RtmpK20lPh/R.INSTALL10915eb5334/gert/libgit2/lib/libgit2.a(annotated_commit.c.o): unrecognized relocation (0x2a) in section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [gert.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘gert’
* removing ‘/GPUFS/smu_ymyu_1/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/gert’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gert’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘gert’ is not available for package ‘usethis’
* removing ‘/GPUFS/smu_ymyu_1/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/usethis’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘usethis’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘usethis’ is not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/GPUFS/smu_ymyu_1/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/devtools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp7IpcmZ/downloaded_packages’
```

And I searched in the Internet, followed the previous suggestion to install the libgit2 in the Linux.
Linux version 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 (root@huawei-2u) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Sat Oct 12 02:01:43 CST 2019

```
> $yum install libgit2
> $yum info libgit2
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
ovl: Error while doing RPMdb copy-up:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/rpm/.dbenv.lock'
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: epel.mirror.angkasa.id
Available Packages
Name        : libgit2
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 0.26.8
Release     : 1.el7_9
Size        : 430 k
Repo        : extras/7/x86_64
Summary     : C implementation of the Git core methods as a library with a solid API
URL         : http://libgit2.github.com/
License     : GPLv2 with exceptions
Description : libgit2 is a portable, pure C implementation of the Git core methods
            : provided as a re-entrant linkable library with a solid API, allowing
            : you to write native speed custom Git applications in any language
            : with bindings.
```

After installing the libgit2, but I still can't install the devtools in Rstudio server. Please help me.